# use my macbook as a wifi hotspot using 802.1x auth

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, hotspot, ps4

I'm connected to eduroam ( uni wifi) and i can't use it with my ps4 ( there are no ethernet cables here ) , the only way is to use my macbook as a wifi hotspot but i can't since it is a 802.1x .
Is there any other way ? Thank you .
ps : I'm on macos Big Sur

Comment: Not easy to tell quite what you're asking, but you cannot use WiFi to both access the Uni network and simultaneously set it as a hotspot. You need one of each connection type to do that. e.g WiFi to Uni, Ethernet to other devices.

Comment: I don't have ethernet ports in my room. what i'm asking is a way to share a 802.1x wifi

Comment: You can't share the same connection you use to connect to the outside world with. SO if you have to use WiFi to connect to the Uni, you have to use something else as your hotspot… Ethernet being the obvious candidate. Imagine you have two cups, one with water, one empty. You can pour water from the full to the empty, but you can't pour it back again *at the same time*.

Comment: 802.1x authentication pretty much means that the connection isn't supposed to be sharable. So I suspect that, if you did find a way to share it, you'd be violating the network's security policy. So don't do that.